# Using scopes with to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

Is there any way to limit the association results returned by `to_json` in a call like `Company.all.to_json(:only=>[:name],:include=>{:users=>...`? Specifically, I'd like to use a scope defined on `User`. I've been looking at various docs and haven't seen scopes mentioned anywhere.